# Removing Attribute in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I'm very new in Magento.
I want to remove one of the attributes in Magento.

Call it PDF Preview.

When i click it, this error message pops up :
[image: Fatal Error]

Can someone please advise what i need to do to remove the Attributes?
I've read the documentation : [Remove custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141874/delete-custom-customer-attribute-in-magento?answertab=active#tab-top)

But i don't undertand how to run the files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file with this content and call it from browser:

> MAGENTO_ROOT/filename.php

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');

$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
$setup->endSetup();
```