# Completely Remove Module in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect, third-party-module

I installed a module with Magento Connect. After install, I found some errors in the backend and removed it from Magento Connect, refreshed, reindexed and cleared cache but still have the error.

When I click to add a new product I see this error:

> There has been an error processing your request

and the file in var/report show

> a:5:{i:0;s:100:"Source model "marketplace/catalog_product_attribute_status" not found for attribute "product_status"";i:1;s:3088:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\asai\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
>   1 C:\xampp\htdocs\asai\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
>   2   C:\xampp\htdocs\asai\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)

How to repair it?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem as a product attribute `product_status` was added by this extension.

Go to **Admin - Catalog - Manages Attributes** and delete this attribute.

---

**Edit:** see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177796/46249

Comment: yes there is a product attribute product_status was added by this extension but when i click on it to remove the attribute there is no delete button how to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

there is a product attribute `product_status` was added by this extension but when i click on it to remove the attribute there is no delete button and impossible in `Catalog>Attributes>Manage AttributeSets` too Because it was System Attribute so After Searching I found This Solution by This Link:
 [How to Remove System Attributes](https://www.host1plus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/magento/magento-administration/how-to-remove-system-attributes)
 And now Its Working Good